# Unable to do the oauth flow and login with linkedin app

Tags: linkedin-api

Tried to login via Oauth using Linkedin App. But seeing this error screen instead of being asked to approve login as one would expect from an Oauth app.

[image: Your Linkedin Network will be back soon error]

Any resolutions or explanations would be appreciated. I reached out to Linkedin Support but they instead asked to open a question on Stack Overflow Instead.

#linkedin